# Using moment.js

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I'm new to programming. I inserted the following code in my HTML head tag:

HTML

```
<script src="moment.min.js"></script>
```

However, when I tried to run the html file on chrome, I got this error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

AND

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined
```

What is wrong? Do I need to install moment? The install commands on this page aren't available on my mac.
http://momentjs.com/

Comment: is *moment.min.js* at the same level as the html file?

Comment: where "moment.min.js" script placed

Comment: moment.js is not included properly i believe

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify right the moment.js, i dont think more than this any problem.
Use following moment js cdn URl instead folder specify

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

hope this helps...

Comment: yup :) just need to add http: before //

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify a path for the js file. Download it, put it in a folder in your project and specify the correct path in the script tag.